# Is AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS a default setting found in settings.py in Django 3?

Tags: django, authentication, django-3.0

Following a book on django, at the point where it is discussing building a custom authentication backend. It states "The `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` settings includes the list of authentication backends for your project. By default, this setting is set as follows: `['django.conrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']`" but nowhere in my settings.py do I see `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.conrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']`.
This book uses Django 2. So I figured something may have changed, but the Django 3 documentation also states "By default, `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` is set to:

```
['django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend']"
```

Should I be looking somewhere else for this setting? I thought all settings were found in settings.py

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django has it's [default settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/#default-settings) if you don't specify one

> A Django settings file doesn’t have to define any settings if it
>   doesn’t need to. Each setting has a sensible default value. These
>   defaults live in the module django/conf/global_settings.py.

Answer (score 0):

add to your settings

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

this will help to auth users from db, if you don't trust to default settings. IF YOU add more auth backends then this default also has to be included to them, as the default value will be overriden.

Comment: The documentation states this is the default value though, so I figured that meant this setting would be included in settings.py after running `django-admin startproject`. Is it getting this default somewhere behind the scenes that I can't see?